# A question on asymptotic analysis

Tags: real-analysis, summation, asymptotics

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$. It is known that, for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\eta\in\mathbb{N}$, $$f(\lambda,\eta) \ge 0 $$

Also $$\lim\limits_{\lambda\to\infty} \sup\limits_{\eta\in\mathbb{N}}f(\lambda,\eta) = \Theta(1)$$

Show that $$\lim\limits_{\lambda\to\infty}\sum\limits_{\eta\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{f(\lambda,\eta)}{1+\lambda\eta^2} = \Theta(\frac{1}{\lambda})$$

---

**What I know**
I know that for any $\eta\in\mathbb{N}$ $$\lim\limits_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\lambda\eta^2} = \Theta(\frac{1}{\lambda})$$

This can be proven by Laurent series expansion of $\frac{1}{1+\lambda\eta^2}$at $\lambda=\infty$, giving us  $$\lim\limits_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\lambda\eta^2} = \sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{r+1}\frac{1}{\eta^{2r}\lambda^{r}} = \Theta(\frac{1}{\lambda})$$

I also know that for any $\lambda>0$, the summation $\sum\limits_{\eta\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{1+\lambda\eta^2}$ is finite.

But I still don't know how to proceed from here. I am convinced that the result I want is true, but I am just not able to prove it. I think its not difficult, but I just don't get it right as to how I can prove it. I am looking for the precise steps for the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\lambda$ is sufficiently large, so that $\sup _n f(\lambda ,n)$ is finite. One has
$$
\lambda \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{f(\lambda ,n)}}{{1 + \lambda n^2 }}}  \le \sup _n f(\lambda ,n)\lambda \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 + \lambda n^2 }}}  \le \sup _n f(\lambda ,n)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}}  = \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6}\sup _n f(\lambda ,n)
$$
Hence, by the condition,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\lambda  \to  + \infty } \lambda \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{f(\lambda ,n)}}{{1 + \lambda n^2 }}}  \le \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\lambda  \to  + \infty } \sup _n f(\lambda ,n) <  + \infty .
$$
On the other hand
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{f(\lambda ,n)}}{{1 + \lambda n^2 }}}  \ge 0 = \frac{0}{\lambda }.
$$